# Delete related object via OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there some clever way how to perform delete in this situation?

```
class Bus(models.Model):  
    wheel = OneToOneField(Wheel)  

class Bike(models.Model):  
    wheel = OneToOneField(Wheel)  
    pedal = OneToOneField(Pedal)

class Car(models.Model):  
    wheel = OneToOneField(Wheel)  

class Wheel(models.Model):  
    somfields

car = Car()    
wheel = Wheel()  
wheel.save()
car.wheel = wheel
car.save()  
car.delete() # I want to delete also wheel (and also all stuff pointing via OneToOneField eg pedal)
```

Do I need to override delete methods of Car, Bike, Bus models or is there some better way? Other option is to create fields car, bike, bus on Wheel model, but it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the thing, since `Car` links to `Wheel`, it is the dependent model in the relationship. Therefore when you delete a `Wheel`, it deletes all dependent models (including related `Car` rows). However when you delete a `Car`, since `Wheel` does not depend on `Car`, it is not removed.

In order to delete parent relations in Django, you can overwrite the `Car`'s `delete` method:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    # ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.wheel.delete()
        return super(self.__class__, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then when doing:

```
Car.objects.get(...).delete()
```

will also delete the `Wheel`.

Comment: Problem with overriding `delete()` method is that it will not be called if you do bulk delete operation as `Car.objects.filter().delete()`

Comment: @Rohan yes you are right. For bulk delete operations aka. querysets as advised by django docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.delete use django signals `post_delete` decorator.

Comment: @Rohan To be specific an excerpt for the above django docs link - >> The delete() method does a bulk delete and does not call any delete() methods on your models. It does, however, emit the pre_delete and post_delete signals for all deleted objects (including cascaded deletions).

Answer (score 11):

Cascading delete is already provided by django, through [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) attribute  value [`CASCADE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE). It is also available for [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) along with [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

> ForeignKey.on_delete
>
> When an object referenced by a ForeignKey is
>   deleted, Django by default emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint
>   ON DELETE CASCADE and also deletes the object containing the
>   ForeignKey.

However, in your models you are putting `OneToOneField` in another model, hence you are not seeing the expected behavior.

Change your models to:

```
class Car(models.Model):  
    somefields

class Wheel(models.Model):  
    somfields
    car = OneToOneField(Car)
```

That is put `OneToOneField` in `Wheel` model instead of `Car`. Now when you delete `Car` model corresponding `Wheel` will also be deleted.

Problem with overriding `delete()` method is that it will not be called if you do bulk delete operation as `Car.objects.filter().delete()`

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to avoid to have car etc fields on the Wheel model. So for me the best solution looks like listen to pre_delete signal, find all OneToOneFields and manually delete them.

Comment: @ChRapO, How does that matter where its defined? You can have `parent_link=True` if you want reverse link.