# How to execute CASCADE on delete?

Tags: python, django, orm, models

I have this model in Django, where a `person` has the same information from the `user` provided by Django plus a little bit more information. When I create a new `person` it requires to create a new `user` also, that's fine. But when I delete a `person` the `user` still remains on my database. What am I missing here ? I would like to delete the `user` too.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User)
    gender = CharField(max_length=1, choices=GenderChoices, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: What does the SQL `CASCADE` instruction do? I've found some relevant documentation about it's usage in Django here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Answer (score 0):

Try to [override the delete method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) on the model (code not tested):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User)
    gender = CharField(max_length=1, choices=GenderChoices, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def delete():
        theuser = User.objects.get(id=user)
        theuser.delete()
```

I have found some relevant documentation about CASCADE usage in Django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sebas, but I think that if I override the delete method I might find some problems with the bulk operations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621653/523168

Comment: Maybe you can use `pre_delete` and `post_delete` signals to create events that handle that issue properly... I haven't played around with signals yet.