# Django Python 3.x - OneToOneField override delete() with ContentTypes

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-3.0, django-contenttypes

Scenario: there is different service types, i.e. clothes_washing, room_cleaning and room_maintenance.
Each one of these services have common fields like service_date for example.

Upon scenario I have model for each service and a `Service` model with common fields. the relation between `Service` model and each service model is `OneToOneField`.

I've tried to override the `delete()` function in `Service` model following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16620382/4719854) and It works for me but for only one service (like wheel in `self.wheel.delete()`). but if I want to delete upon the service type? how to achieve that approach?

my **models.py**:

```
class ClothesWashing(models.Model):
    # special fields for clothes_washing
    service = models.OneToOneField(Service, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)

class RoomCleaning(models.Model):
    # special fields for room_cleaning 
    service = models.OneToOneField(Service, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)

class Service(models.Model):
    # common fields for all services

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #here I wanna "roomcleaning" attribute to be dynamic upon content type
        self.roomcleaning.delete()
        return super(self.__class__, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **`on_delete`** parameters to **`CASCADE`**:

```
class ClothesWashing(models.Model):
    # special fields for clothes_washing
    service = models.OneToOneField(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class RoomCleaning(models.Model):
    # special fields for room_cleaning 
    service = models.OneToOneField(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

The [**`on_delete=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) specifies what should happen when the item to which it refers is removed. So if `Service` is removed, and there is a `ClothesWashing` model that refers to it, then you can specify what to do.

By using [**`CASCADE`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE), you will remove the related `ClothesWashing` object as well, or as specified in the documentation:

> Cascade deletes. Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint `ON DELETE CASCADE` and also deletes the object containing the `ForeignKey`.

It is better to implement it with this triggers, since methods like `.delete()` are *not* always called by the ORM when deleting in bulk. So `Service.objects.all().delete()` will delete all services, but will *never* call the `.delete()` method of your `Service`. By defining the triggers, you specify to Django what should happen with items that relate to it.

In this specific case, you perhaps might want to work with [*model inheritance* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance). Django can implement some boilerplate logic itself (like `OneToOneField`s to the parent model, etc.).

**EDIT**: If you want to delete the service if the given `ClothesWashing`, `RoomCleaning`, etc. are removed, you can override the `.delete()` method to delete that one too, you can for example make an abstract base class with:

```
class ServiceBase(models.Model):
    # special fields for clothes_washing
    service = models.OneToOneField(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        service = self.service
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
        self.service.delete()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ClothesWashing(ServiceBase):
    # …
    pass

class RoomCleaning(ServiceBase):
    # …
    pass
```

But likely if you use the ORM eventually some objects will not be removed, because of said ways to circumvent this.

Comment: correct me if I got you wrong, that means if i set ```on_delete=models.CASCADE``` when I delete ```Service``` the ```ClothesWashing``` will be also deleted. but what if I deleted ```ClothesWashing```? will ```Service``` be deleted too ?

Comment: @PoulaAdel: no, but that was not the case in your original design either. This is however not easy, since if you override `.delete()` it will *not* be triggered if you delete objects in bulk. But you can, as a "poor man solution" indeed override `.delete()` and hope that it does not happen.